# Error in R "Function cannot be found" while creating calculation

Tags: r

Could you please help me identify the error in my code? The code return with an error

> "function cannot be found"

Thank you!

```
> QueueHW <- read.csv('C:/Users/matpo/Desktop/Queue_HW.csv', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
> summary(QueueHW)
 ï..Number_of_Servers  Service_Rate       Lambda  
 Min.   : 7.00        Min.   : 98.0   Min.   :82  
 1st Qu.:10.25        1st Qu.:143.5   1st Qu.:82  
 Median :13.50        Median :189.0   Median :82  
 Mean   :13.50        Mean   :189.0   Mean   :82  
 3rd Qu.:16.75        3rd Qu.:234.5   3rd Qu.:82  
 Max.   :20.00        Max.   :280.0   Max.   :82  
> str(QueueHW)
'data.frame':   14 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ï..Number_of_Servers: int  7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
 $ Service_Rate        : int  98 112 126 140 154 168 182 196 210 224 ...
 $ Lambda              : int  82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 82 ...
> QueueHW %>%
+   mutate <- (Waittime=(Lambda/(Service_Rate(Service_Rate - Lambda))))
Error in Service_Rate(Service_Rate - Lambda) : 
  could not find function "Service_Rate"
```

Comment: Try: `mutate(Waittime=Lambda/(Service_Rate*(Service_Rate - Lambda)))` assuming you're order of operations for the denominator is Service_Rate times the difference of service_rate and Lambda. The error is due to the fact that the way you've written the pipe, it's calling the `Service_Rate` as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Service_Rate(Service_Rate - Lambda)`

What you're saying here is: I'm calling the *function* `Service_Rate`, with argument `Service_Rate - Lambda`.

So R complains that it doesn't know about any function `Service_Rate`.

I suspect you're typing over some formula, where usually when variables need to be multiplied, no sign is put between them (e.g. Newtons `F = ma`, which means F = m * a). But when programming, you need to include it, so that would be `Service_Rate * (Service_Rate - Lambda)`. Or something else if you've simply made a typo.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, Emil! I am new to R, so this really helps! I corrected the formula, however now I have "object not found" error

Comment: @vethraut Did you try my proposed line of code: `QueueHW %>% dplyr::mutate(Waittime=Lambda/(Service_Rate*(Service_Rate-Lambda)))`